# How to create Redis cluster on different machines?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I am trying to run my python scripts on Redis cluster which I want to create on different machines and not a single local machine.
Can someone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: You can follow many online documents for cluster installation one such [https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/big-data/how-to-install-and-configure-a-redis-cluster-on-ubuntu-1604/] and extensive tutorial [https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial], try this out if you face any issues post them here.

Comment: Yes, thankyou but from what I could find online, they are trying to setup redis cluster on a single local machine and not multiple ones. Even the cluster tutorial on the official website, tried to create in on a single machine, which is why they are giving address as 127.0.0.1 . If they were using multiple machines, shouldn't we specify IP addresses for wach of these machines in the cluster, Like it is done in this line: ./redis-cli --cluster create 127.0.0.1:6001 127.0.0.1:6002 127.0.0.1:6003 127.0.0.1:6004 127.0.0.1:6005 127.0.0.1:6006 --cluster-replicas 1

Comment: if all machines can communicate, then replace those 127.0.0.1 with the machine ip address respectively.

Comment: Okay, can you tell me in much more detail how to do that? Like for each of these machines different conf files have to be created and the ports also need to be decided for TCP connections. i'm not really sure how to do that? Do you have any resource to get me started with it?

Comment: Also, now if for example, i have to run python scripts how will i know which node to run it on and how to do that?

Comment: for each node create redis.conf file similar to below with the port number and ip.
|
`port <port_num>
bind <ip_address>
 
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes_<port_num>.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
cluster-slave-validity-factor 1`

start each of the server as `redis-server ./redis.conf`

`redis-cli --cluster create <ipaddress:port>'s --cluster-replicas 0`

You can connect to any node in the cluster, your request should redirect to proper node in the cluster.

Comment: How can i connect to one node in the cluster? And the whole purpose of running my deep learning model on redis cluster is to increase its performance. So by running my files, how will i make sure that all the nodes in the cluster are all being used while my python scripts are running?

Comment: Also, for different machines, how can i find out which TCP port to connect to?